# Create a CSS layout that occupies an iPad's viewport

Tags: css, web-applications

I would like to create a web page that fills up an iPad viewport completely. I also want to ensure that content doesn't extend past the viewport to prevent any page-level scrolling.

I had attempted a 1024x768 portrait layout, but I ended up getting clipping horizontally, and the page's content extended past the bottom edge of the viewport.

I added this to the :

And I have a simple #container div that sits right under the body, styled like this:

```
#container {
width: 768px;
max-width:768px;
height:1024px;
max-height:1024px;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

Anyone know how I can achieve a layout that is fixed to the dimension of the iPad?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fill any screen, also nice and responsive.

```
#container {
    position: absolute,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
}
```

Comment: Lol, man you guys are quick! This looks like a great solution! I did manage to get it working with fixed pixel dimensions, I wasn't factoring in the 20px the notification bar takes up! To ask another question, what are the dimensions I should provide to a designer if I wanted a layout fixed to an iPad viewport? 1004 x 764 would be correct, no?

Comment: This is a really handy technique: it basically pushes all four edges of the box to the viewport's edges, without needing to specify a width and height. You can specify any co-ordinates you like, of course. A useful variation is to set 3 co-ordinates, plus a width or height, to create flexy scroll bars, etc.

Comment: Heh - we exist to serve! One thing with pixel dimensions - you'll get scrollbars if the device goes portrait. This technique will fit regardless of orientation

Comment: The thing about specifying pixels is it's very unresponsive. Any time a new device comes out (hello iPad mini), you'll be stuck updating your code. This way simply uses all available space regardless.

Comment: Regarding the iPad mini, Mike - it has the same device-pixel resolution as normal iPads, just on a physically smaller screen (which is a shame, actually, since it'd be better to be able to adjust accordingly).

Comment: Ah fair enough. Well this will work on an iPhone 1G! Ha-hah! (warning: not tested on iPhone 1G)

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use % ?

for example:

```
#container {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: 100% height won't have the right effect - this is relative to the document, not the viewport, and the document is only as high as it's content.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the HTML, you could use the meta tag for viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Just a thought.

Comment: This is a good thing to add to a page like this, but it won't affect the dimensions of any of the elements on the page, so it's not really an answer to the question.